# Directly reference parameter properties js

Tags: javascript, jquery, import, parameters, lazy-loading

Does anyone know if is it syntactically possible to apply the parameter properties as local scope methods for the parent function to reference.

The module is very large which increase page load times and shouldn't be imported via import() at top level.

```
import {method1, method2, method3} from "./module.js" //not an option
```

```
//Working example.
$('some-id').on('click', () => {
   import ("./module.js") 
   .then( (module) => {
   module.method();
   module.method2();
   module.method3();
   // module methods...

   
  });
}
```

```
//Something along these lines.
$('some-id').on('click', () => {
   import ("./module.js") 
   .then( ( module ) => {
   method();
   method2();
   method3();
   //Apply the module methods to function scope without direct reference to the parameter
   //this would save some time and loads of repetition if possible, question is can anything similar be done.
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be pretty similar!

```
$('some-id').on('click', async () => {
  const { method, method2, method3 } = await import("./module.js");
  method();
  method2();
  method3();
});
```